# What platforms are supported by gio and gvfs library?

Tags: gnome, glib, gio

When writing an application using the GIO and GVFS libraries from the GNOME stack what platforms will my application be available for? Will it be possible to compile the application on Windows, Solaris or *BSD, for example? Are the GIO/GVFS and dependent libraries available as binary packages on those systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIO is part of glib; it uses POSIX APIs so it should work on all *nix systems, and it does have some support for Windows. GVFS is a client-server system, includes *nix-only headers and doesn't seem like it supports Windows at all.

I would start with the glib binaries on http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html and go from there.